# Analyser node bad data on oscillator

Tags: javascript, fft, web-audio-api

```js
let ctx = new AudioContext(),
  analyser = ctx.createAnalyser(),
  oscillator = ctx.createOscillator(),
  data = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);

oscillator.connect(analyser);
oscillator.start();

setTimeout(()=>{
  analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(data);
  console.log(oscillator.frequency, data);
}, 1000);
```

Oscillator by default makes 440hz sine wave(`oscillator.frequency` details), but analyser don't detects it as main wave. In my case values about 440hz is -200db, but about 220hz is -180db, what is louder.

How to detect main frequency by analyser? In my case firtly I used microphone, but oscillator doesn't works. What's wrong with FFT?

Comment: Ran your snippet on a machine with a sample rate of 44.1 kHz.  The relevant analyser output is: "20": -28.359, "21": -28.948.  Bin 20 corresponds to a frequency of about 430 Hz. Bin 21 is 452 Hz.  This is reasonable with a default FFT size of 2048, where each bin is about 21 Hz wide.

Comment: @RaymondToy, how to calculate bin number?

Answer (score 0):

Bin number isn't frequency. You need to check bin with number `2 * bin count * frequency / sampling rate` , where `bin count = fft size / 2`

@Raymond toy, thank you